# How to spin a new thread if data is available in a queue to process.

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a function that zip streams data into a bytebuffer, from that bytebuffer I create 5000lines/chunks, now I am trying to write these chunks back to s3 bucket in separate files, since I am using AWS Lambda I have cannot let single thread handle all the workflow as there 5 minute constraint after which AWS Lambda times out, coming from Java background where threads are pretty simple to implement but in python I am getting confused how to execute pool of thread to take care of `uploading file to s3` part of my process, here is my code:

```
import io
import zipfile
import boto3
import sys
import multiprocessing
# from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 'us-east-1')


def stream_zip_file():
    # pool = ThreadPool(threads)
    start_time_main = time.time()
    start_time_stream = time.time()
    obj = s3.Object(
        bucket_name='monkey-business-dev-data',
        key='sample-files/daily/banana/large/banana.zip'
    )
    end_time_stream = time.time()
    # process_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    buffer = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read())
    output = io.BytesIO()
    print (buffer)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
    foo2 = z.open(z.infolist()[0])
    print(sys.getsizeof(foo2))
    line_counter = 0
    file_clounter = 0
    for line in foo2:
        line_counter += 1
        output.write(line)
        if line_counter >= 5000:
            file_clounter += 1
            line_counter = 0
            # pool.map(upload_to_s3, (output, file_clounter))
            # upload_to_s3(output, file_clounter)
            # process_queue.put(output)
            output.close()
            output = io.BytesIO()
    if line_counter > 0:
        # process_queue.put(output)
        # upload_to_s3(output, file_clounter)
        # pool.map(upload_to_s3, args =(output, file_clounter))
        output.close()
    print('Total Files: {}'.format(file_clounter))
    print('Total Lines: {}'.format(line_counter))
    output.seek(0)
    start_time_upload = time.time()

    end_time_upload = time.time()

    output.close()
    z.close()
    end_time_main = time.time()

    print('''
    main: {}
    stream: {}
    upload: {}
    '''.format((end_time_main-start_time_main),(end_time_stream-start_time_stream),(end_time_upload-start_time_upload)))


def upload_to_s3(output, file_name):
    output.seek(0)
    s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket='monkey-business-dev-data', Key='sample-files/daily/banana/large/{}.txt'.format(file_name),
        ServerSideEncryption='AES256',
        Body=output,
        ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'
    )

#     consumer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_consumer, args=(process_queue))
#     consumer_process.start()
#
#
# def data_consumer(queue):
#     while queue.empty() is False:



if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream_zip_file()
```

Now I have tried several ways to do it, my specific requirement is to have threadpool with size of 10 threads and these threads would always pool a queue, if chunk is available to upload on queue thread would execute and start uploading the chunk meanwhile one thread would always continuously pool the queue for new chunk and if chunk gets available a new thread (if thread 1 is still busy in s3 upload) will automatically start and upload the file to s3 and so on. I have checked many answers here and on google but nothing seems to work or make sense to my feeble mind.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of lambda here. You don't run threads within a lambda function, you create new instances of the function as necessary.

Comment: We can create threads within Lambda functions, this is a single Lambda event where the given Lambda would process a large zip file and bifurcate it into small chunks and upload it to various s3 buckets then the next step function would get executed, I have always spun threads in Lambda for fast performance but in Java.